# Jupyter notebook extension loading eratically

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I load extensions to IPython notebook (powered by Jupyter) with the following command in `~\.ipython\profile_default\static\custom\custom.js`.

```
IPython.load_extensions("calico-spell-check", "calico-document-tools");
```

The extensions are correctly loaded in the first notebook I open. But they are typically disabled in the following notebooks I open. Then when I close, reopen, etc. the notebooks they are loaded (seldom) or not (often) without any specific message in the console.

Is it a problem of compatibility with Jupyter or rather a bad configuration of mine?

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a race condition. Most of the instruction on how to activate extension in `custom.js` are wrong/too old when they tell you to directly copy past code in `custom.js`. Please follow official docs, use requirejs, and register the extension following the information in official docs.